# How to display arabic numerics when using NSNumberFormatter with India locale?

Tags: ios, macos, nsnumberformatter

The following with return `१२३४५६७८९०` instead of `123456790`:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "hi_IN")
numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(1234567890)
```

Is there a way to configure `NSNumberFormatter` so that arabic numeral is used?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get `١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠` then use the localeIdentifier `ar_SA` or `ar_IN`

If you want to still get the return value as 123456789 then you can use any other indian locale that does not contain the numerals in its respective script. For e.g. en_IN. Refer https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273 for the locale identifiers that you want to use.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without changing locale? I want to keep all other features of having a locale as `ar_LB` for example and still use arabic numerals 1, 2, 3, etc.